# How can i solve this second-order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integration

**My Problem** is, this given second order non-linear differential equation: $$yy^{\prime\prime}=2(y^{\prime})^{2}-2y^{\prime}$$

I am really stuck with second-order differential equations.

**My Approach**: i was given the advise to solve first $$y^{\prime}=p(y)$$ and to determine $p$ but i didn't managed to get it.

I thought this: $$yy^{\prime\prime}=2(y^{\prime})^{2}-2y^{\prime}$$
could lead to: $$2y^{\prime}=2(y^{\prime})^{2}-yy^{\prime\prime}$$
$$y^{\prime}=(y^{\prime})^{2}-\frac{yy^{\prime\prime}}{2}$$

But i don't get it and i can't solve the equation.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo: I think you mean $\dfrac{\tan\left(\sqrt{C_1} (x+C_2)\right)}{\sqrt{C_1}}$

Comment: $y''=\frac{dy'}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dy'}{dy}$

Comment: @Robert Israel: Yes, thank you. I removed the comment because I was not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ODE has trivial solution $y=0$.

Now we have to solve case $y\neq 0$:

After dividing equation with $y^3$: 
$$\frac{y y''-2y'^2}{y^3}=\frac{-2y'}{y^3},$$
we get $(\frac{y'}{y^2})'$ on the left side and $(\frac{1}{y^2})'$ on the right side. Therefore,
$$\frac{y'}{y^2}=\frac{1}{y^2}+C,$$
$$y'=1+Cy^2,$$
$$\frac{dy}{1+Cy^2}=dx.$$
After integration, we have 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{C}}\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{C}y)=x+D.$$
Finally,
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{C}}\tan{(\sqrt{C}(x+D))}=y.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You can write your differential equation in the form
$$ \dfrac{y''}{y' - 1} = 2 \dfrac{y'}{y} $$
and both sides can be integrated...

Comment: No, $\int 2 \dfrac{y'}{y}\ dx = 2 \ln y + C$.  
And similarly for $\int \dfrac{y''}{y'-1}\ dx$.

Comment: oh okay. But $\int \dfrac{y''}{y'-1}\ dx=ln(y'-1)+C$... and this would result in $$ln(y'-1)+C=2 \ln y+C$$  ... right?

Comment: Right (of course, the two $C$'s are not necessarily equal).  Now exponentiate to get rid of the logs.

Comment: okay, should i get this in the end?  $$y=\tan (x+C)$$

Comment: Not quite.  There's another constant...

Comment: how? i don't get it, sorry

Comment: $y' = 1 + A y^2$ is a separable differential equation.